# How to set an alarm at a specific date at any chosen time?

Tags: android, datepicker, alarm, timepicker

So this is my code, it works but i can't set an alarm except at 12:00 AM
i want the user to set an alarm at a specific date, like the one given below but to be able to set it at any time of the day not just midnight...can anyone help ?

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    pickerDate.init(
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            null);

    pickerTime.setCurrentHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    buttonSetAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
                    pickerDate.getMonth(),
                    pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
                    0);


            if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date/Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                setAlarm(cal);
            }



        }});
}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);






    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
            pickerDate.getMonth(),
            pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
            pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
            pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
            0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);



    try {
    Date date12_25 = format.parse("12/25/2017");

    Lebanon.put(date12_25,"Christmas Day");
        for(Date k : Lebanon.keySet()){

            if(cal.getTime().equals(k)){

                String val = (String)Lebanon.get(k);
                info.setText("Your alarm is set for :"+k+", on:  "+val);
            }

        }



    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }format.format(new Date());


    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "i can't set an alarm except at 12:00 AM"? Does your alarm only ever fire at 12am? Does it just not get set if the chosen time is not 12am?

Comment: yes exactly , i have to set my time picker to 12 am to be able to set the alarm. i want to set the alarm at a date but whatever the time is. @MikeM.

Comment: So, you're saying, ignoring the date, if you don't set the `TimePicker` to exactly 12:00am, you get the "Invalid Date/Time" `Toast`?

Comment: no no "Invalid Date/Time" only happens if the date time settings set are before the current ones as in in the past, the problem is here i think if(cal.getTime().equals(k))  but i dont really know how to fix it... @MikeM.

Comment: i only gave you Date date12_25 = format.parse("12/25/2017");

    Lebanon.put(date12_25,"Christmas Day"); but the hashmap has much more where these came from

Comment: OK, well, that's what I was asking in my first comment. So `setAlarm()` _is_ being called, but the alarm's just not running as expected? Also, in the code you've posted, you're setting the alarm with `targetCal`, which was passed into `setAlarm()`, and the stuff in the `try` isn't changing that at all, so it's not clear why that stuff's even there.

Comment: ok so..the stuff in the try are a hashmap of holidays, the user will have these dates in a textbox and will choose which date(holiday) he wants to set his reminder to, and the for loop is just iterating through these holiday dates to see if the user specified date matches them...but since im using if(cal.getTime().equals(k))  to match the dates in the hashmap and on the datepicker by the user, its checking the equality of the dates to the milliseconds, i just want it to be regardless of the time... sorry and thank you for bearing with me @MikeM.

Comment: Well, if you're somehow _not_ calling `alarmManager.set()` in some of the code you've omitted, then I think I'm following you. In that case, yeah, that would be the problem. In the `Calendar` you're using for the `cal.getTime().equals(k)` comparison, don't use the `TimePicker` values to set the hour and minute. Just set those both to zero, then if `cal` and `k` have the same date values, they'll be equal.

Comment: i tried setting them to 0 it doesnt work, but i just found out something.. when i used date=format.parse() it automatically registers the time as 00:00:00 to that given date... now i really dont know how to fix this...@MikeM.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly why I said to set them to zero, so as to match the parsed `Date`. If it's still not working, then you've got other problems with your logic in some unseen code. You'll have to continue debugging to figure out where.

Comment: turns out you were right the problem was with the minutes and seconds from the timepicker so thank you @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    MediaPlayer mp;  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alrm   );  
        mp.start();  
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  
}
```

Start Alarm-

```
//  i = int time from calander.
     int i = 12;  
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                                          this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);  
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                                          + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);  
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: lol i think i know where u copied that from but no that doesnt help one bit with my timing issue